# How much damage is caused by smoking 2-3 cigarettes on a healthy body?

Tags: smoking

I do not know how bad does 2-3 cigarettes a day on the average healthy body.

Comments made me point out rightfully, so I have to specify:

"2-3 cigarettes without increasing the dosage over time."

I do not want to include genetic factors on this issue.

So, maybe there is a study or something on this topic.

Does it cause a real damage, or to this quantities the body recovers.

Comment: Welcome to HealthSE! What has your research shown so far? Please take the [tour](https://health.stackexchange.com/tour) and read the [help](https://health.stackexchange.com/help).

Comment: Also clarify - Do you mean just a one time thing? Or starting a habit?

Comment: well, 2-3 cigarettes without increasing the dosage over time.

Answer (score 3):

The moment you start smoking a cigarette, the damage to your body begins.

Not only physical, but mental health also begins to decline.

Here are a few things that happen inside a human body once smoking begins...

1. Apart from nicotine, some 3000+ harmful chemicals enter your body and stir up chemical reactions!
2. The blood in your body starts to clot.
3. Nicotine makes your brain to change its functions without you realizing it!
4. The ability of your lungs to filter bad substances gets reduced and well, over time, it helps you achieve lung cancer.
5. Over time, low libido, erectile problems will occur.
6. Women who smoke may invite cervical cancer apart from, pregnancy issues, premature delivery.
7. Invitation to various types of cancers such as, throat, lips, voice box, tongue besides damage to your nails, hair, skin, you name it!

According to American Academy of Dermatology, smoking contributes in premature ageing.

Ref link: https://www.aad.org/public/skin-hair-nails/anti-aging-skin-care/causes-of-aging-skin

The natural ageing process gets momentum due to chemicals in the cigarette and helps you get wrinkles and stained skin at an early age!

Here are a few things you need to know, if you're going to smoke 2-3 cigarettes/day:

**Physical Damage**:

- Threat to cardiovascular system
- Respiratory damage
- Brain damage
- Damage to reproductive system
- Damage to skin, hair, nails
- Bad breath

and so on!

Your body does recover initially as its immune system is strong!

As the time passes, and so does the smoke, it also begins to deteriorate and over time, you become eligible to the above mentioned conditions!

So it's upto you to decide whether to let go of your own healthy body into smoke or make it count.

Quit smoking my friend.

Comment: This is very virtuous, displaying good morals. But does it answer the question concerning the dosage and backs these findings up with references? – I guess nobody in their right mind will say smoking is healthy and the general agreement points towards not starting or quitting as best options. Fundamentalist morality tales often backfire in terms of achieving harm reduction. Coming down from 60 cigs to 3 day is an improvement. To repeat: I agree with what you wrote in principle, but in the context of the question asked it might be much improved by *focusing more* on doses.

Comment: @LangLangC spot on.